# Laravel ajax post, not getting response, error or db insert

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make a POST ajax call that will take a form input value, pass it, through a route, to the contoller which will call an insert function. I've set my route, my insert function, my controller and my blade with the ajax call, but when I fill the input and hit the submit button, there is no response or error in the console and no record inserted into the database.

Maybe I'm totally overlooking something but is it clear what I'm missing or doing wrong here? Perhaps I should be debugging this differently as well?

Route.php

```
Route::post('insertFruit', 'Controller@insertFruit');
```

controller.php

```
public function insertFruit(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $productComment = $request->productComment;

        $fruitService = new fruitService();
        $fruitService->insertListRecord($productComment);
    }
}
```

fruitService.php

```
public function insertListRecord($productComment)
{
    $link = DB::conn();
    $sql = "CALL fruit.fruitInsert(?, ?)";

    $exec = odbc_exec($link, $sql);

    $prep = odbc_prepare($link, $sql);
    if ($prep === false) {
        $error = odbc_errormsg($link);
        if (!empty($error)) {
            throw new \Exception($error);
        }
    }

    $exec = odbc_execute($prep, array($productComment));
    if ($exec === false) {
        $error = odbc_errormsg($link);
        if (!empty($error)) {
            throw new \Exception($error);
        }
    }
}
```

blade.php

```
    <form id="productForm" class="uk-form uk-width-1-1">
    <div class="uk-grid">
        <div class="uk-width-1-1">
            <label class="uk-form-label" for="">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="productComment" id="" cols="70" rows="5" placeholder="Optional"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-grid">
        <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">
            <button id="save" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large" style="padding:0 50px;">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

    $("#save").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var productComment = $("input[name=productComment]").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/insertFruit',
        data:{

            productComment:productComment
        },
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        type:"POST",
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
             alert('Exception:', exception);
         }
    });

});
```

Comment: What does your form's HTML look like?

Comment: My bad, it's in the blade now

Comment: What happens if you remove the `if ($request->ajax()) {` check?

Comment: @Adam the same unfortunately

Comment: Any error logs filling up at this point or the stacktrace error page?

Comment: I'm getting a preview error page from "Network" in the chrome dev tools. It shows under "Form Data" that I'm passing a value but it doesn't show all form data, is there a reason it would only pass from one input?

Comment: The only input I see is `productComment` which is a text area, the console log should so everything within that box in the post params (along with the name itself).

Comment: Ok I did get it to post from there now, it gives an OK 200 response but still no inserted record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form's HTML, you'll need to set it's method to POST, since your route is expecting a POST method.

```
 <form id="productForm" class="uk-form uk-width-1-1" method="post">
```

Comment: Good point, I did that and I do now get a 500 error in the console

Comment: Then it's likely any issue in the controller.php or fruitService.php at this point. Will update answer if I track it down.

Comment: SO the ajax is passing with a 200, is there a better way for me to return an error from my prepare or execute?

Comment: Haven't worked with ODBC much, but this may help? http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-errormsg.php - Though in my experience, it doesn't always return the previous message (var_dumping sometimes is blank).

Comment: I think it's an issue with the form data. It needs to be passed as a string in single quotes like 'category' . Is there something I should be doing to make sure it passes it that way?

Comment: Could you give an example if the input you're using for the text area that's failing?

Comment: Thanks, I actually finally got it all figured out